# Chevy 350 fuel pump pushrod/lifter

Tags: chevrolet, camshaft

this might be a stupid question but do I have to replace the mechanical fuel pump pushrod/lifter like a normal lifter when swapping in a new cam?

Comment: I don't *think* you have to, but you might depending on condition. Does it appear worn? Can you add some description or pictures of the wear?

Comment: I haven’t started tearing into the engine yet just a thought when buying everything I needed to do the swap

Comment: I never had a Chevy 350 ,, but I had Olds 350 ("R") and Buick 350 ("X") and they  both worked by lever , not push rod.

Answer (score 1):

Only if it is worn badly on either end, they are cheap to replace. but rarely have I seen a bad one, probably 3 in tearing down over 1,000 small block chevy's, lube it good when installing especially on the cam end.

Advice: be sure to use break in cam lube on all surfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I haven’t torn into the engine just yet to know how worn it is. Just a thought/question I had while ordering everything. I’m cheap but I’ll be on the safe side and put out a couple extra dollars for one.